# Shuffling a list in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, shuffle

What's the best/easiest way to shuffle a long list in Mathematica?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
RandomSample[list]
```

Yes, it's really that simple.  At least since version 6.

Before `RandomSample` was introduced, one might use:

```
#[[ Ordering[Random[] & /@ #] ]] & @ list
```

Comment: Prior to version 6, I was using `Combinatorica'RandomPermutation`, which is both faster and safer, since it can never produce identical elements.

Comment: @Leonid Szabolcs stated: "Combinatorica also has a RandomPermutation function (earlier versions).

I am looking for other/better solutions, if there are any."  I was answering with that in mind, but that should indeed be a better solution pre-6.0.

Comment: Oops, missed that one. But then I don't understand - the solution based on `Combinatorica'RandomPermutation` seems superior to me, why bother using `Random` - based one at all (this is a question to @Szabolcs really, not you)?

Comment: @Leonid, I was looking for an answer for v8, where Combinatorica is deprecated and issues a warning when loaded.  For earlier versions it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Before RandomSample was introduced, I've used the below MathGroup-function heavily, though RandomSample is faster at least by one magnitude on my machine.

```
In[128]:= n = 10;
          set = Range@n

Out[129]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

In[130]:= Take[set[[Ordering[RandomReal[] & /@ Range@n]]], n]

Out[130]= {8, 4, 5, 2, 3, 10, 7, 9, 6, 1}
```

Other problem besides performance is that if the same random reals are hit twice (improbable, though possible) Ordering will not give these two in random order.

Comment: Pardon me, but that is some dodgy code you have there.  (1) `RandomReal[] & /@ Range@n` could be replaced with `Random[] & /@ set` or usually faster `RandomReal[1, Length@set]`. (2) `Take[... , n]` isn't doing anything here, and can be removed.  Therefore, the code should be:  `set[[ Ordering@RandomReal[1, Length@set] ]]`

Comment: Actually, using `RandomReal` doesn't make any sense, since it was introduced in version 6 along with `RandomSample`.  Therefore, this makes the most sense for pre-version-6 shuffle:  `#[[ Ordering[ Random[]& /@ # ] ]] &`

Answer (score 1):

Currently I use

```
list[[PermutationList@RandomPermutation@Length[list]]]
```

This is for Mathematica 8.  Combinatorica also has a RandomPermutation function (earlier versions).

I am looking for other/better solutions, if there are any.